# Cleaning up Twitter Bootstrap code with Custom CSS Sheet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I just started to use Twitter Bootstrap and it seems very messy in the sense that your designing the site in the html and there is no separation.  I am wondering if there's anyway to clean it up by embeding the bootstrap classes in my own custom class.

For Example:

instead of doing this for the navigation bar in the html.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top"></div>
```

I want to do something like this in the html and css respectively.

```
<div class="customnav"></div>

.customnav {
            .navbar 
            .navbar-inverse 
            .navbar-static-top
 }
```

This doesn't seem to work for me at the moment, but I am wondering if I can do something like that so to separation presentation and semantics.  Sorry if this is a dumb question, and a newb.

Comment: css is not written this way... try `<div class="customnav navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top"></div>`

Comment: That's so clunky though.  Is there anyway to embed multiple classes in one class.  So that I only use one div class per section in the html?

Answer (score 3):

While css can't be written that way, you can use a preprocessor like less, sass or stylus. They will actually let you use your example (the .customnav with other classes or mixins) right in your style.less, style.scss, or style.styl.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, like tzvig said, CSS doesn't work like that. Fortunately, we don't have to write just plain vanilla CSS. [Bootstrap is written with LESS](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#less), a [CSS preprocessor](https://github.com/showcases/css-preprocessors), which makes CSS (and Bootstrap, for that matter) a lot more tolerable. Instead of [messing up your HTML](http://ruby.bvision.com/blog/please-stop-embedding-bootstrap-classes-in-your-html) with tons of those (wonderfully functional, mostly semantic) class attributes, try writing [LESS](http://lesscss.org) (or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com)), which is fully compatible with CSS... so it's less like learning a(nother) new language and more like adding some new tricks. Best of luck!